# What is difference between adit and advenit?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-comparison, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In LLPSI I was introduced to two verbs "adit" and "advenit", but what is difference between them if both of them mean "to go to"? Same to "abit" and "exit".

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary? [adeo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adeo#Latin) and [advenio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advenio#Latin) don't both mean "go to".

Comment: @Cairnarvon When I was reading LLPSI, I never checked a dictionary for any word in the book. I gradually found out that my interpretations of words were wrong sometimes, but my memory of every word is well anchored in context! I recommend it, especially if supplemented by asking people when you can't unravel a confusion on your own.

Comment: @BenKovitz I cannot recommend that at all. Not checking a dictionary is a recipe for trouble in *any* language, but especially one that you're learning. How many people misunderstand the word "morbid" or "travesty"? Suggesting to forego a dictionary is intentionally handicapping yourself with zero benefit.

Comment: @cmw When reading words without a context that makes their meanings clear, yes. LLPSI, though, is thoughtfully designed to bring you every new word in a context that makes it clear. This is the main idea of Ørberg's "natural method". Going without a dictionary keeps you from grounding your understanding of the words in your native language. BTW, I never _needed_ to check a dictionary while reading _Familia Romana_ (though a few words had me puzzled for a day or two).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've figured out that *adit* and *advenit* are just *it* and *venit* with *ad* added as a prefix. If you're not clear on the difference between *it* and *venit*, see chapter VI, line 20 for *it* and chapter III, line 21 for *venit*:

> Ecce Iūlius et quattuor servī in viā. Iūlius ab oppidō ad vīllam suam **it**.

> Iūlia plōrat et Aemiliam vocat: "Mamma! Mam-ma!
> Mārcus mē pulsat!"
> Aemilia **venit**.

By the way, the first occurrence of each word is listed in the index. Sometimes it's hard to look up, though, because each verb is listed in its infinitive form; e.g. *it* is listed under *īre*.

If the difference is still not clear, look at the context of the use of "Venī!" at chapter IV, line 27. Notice that it's not "Ī!"

If, even after looking at these contexts, you're still not sure of the difference, reply in a comment and I'll translate *it* and *venit* into English.

---

With *abit* and *exit*, the difference is the preposition. If you're not yet sure of the difference between *ab* and *ex,* look up their first occurrences in the index, and if that doesn't work, then reply in a comment and I'll explain that in English, too.

---

You might be surprised, if you are just starting, to see how easy it is to pick up differences in meaning between Latin words just by noticing the contexts where they occur in LLPSI. Ørberg usually takes care to introduce each new word in a context that makes its meaning especially appropriate or easy to grasp.

Ørberg often includes a marginal note in Latin at the first occurrence of a word. Sometimes, as with *ex,* the marginal note includes a diagram. Often when people ask me the meaning of a word in LLPSI, I point them to its first occurrence and then we discover that they never saw the marginal note.

Answer (score 1):

I looks as if [Ben Kovitz's answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/20848/13473) intends for you to look through your book to infer those word meanings. **If you still wish to try that, ignore my answer.** Otherwise, here is my take:

I believe that *adit* means to go towards an extent or a location without external prompting, while *advenit* means to come towards (hence *venit*) a physical location with either prompting or some form of intention. Of course, that *ad* in the front of these words means "to/towards".

*Abit* and *exit* just have different prepositions attached to them. The preposition *ab* means "away [from]", while *ex* means "out of". They simply imply different situations, and will be more appropriate for some than others.

In conclusion, their translations would be:

- adire, *to go towards*
- abire, *to go away from*
- exire, *to go out of*
- advenire, *to come towards*

I have put *advenire* at the bottom to differentiate it, as it has a different "stem".
Hope that this helps!